# Unable to iterate on rows (kusto, Azure data explored) via golang

Tags: azure, go, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to run execute a stored_query_result using the **MGMT** function roughly as :

```
query_to_run := statement.UnsafeAdd(query)
iter, err := kustoClient.Mgmt(ctx, kustoDbName, query_to_run)

err = iter.DoOnRowOrError(func(row *table.Row, e *kustoErrors.Error) error {
        if e != nil {
            utils.JsonGenericError(w, fmt.Sprintf("Error processing row: %s", e), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return e
        }
        // fmt.Println(row.String())
        // fmt.Println(row.ExtractValues())
        fmt.Println(row.Values)
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error returned by DoOnRowOrError
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }
```

I primarily keep ending with the following error no matter what

```
Error: Op(OpMgmt): Kind(KInternal): DataTable.Columns(v1) had string entry with either .ColumnType/.DataType set to SByte, which is not supported
```

Can someone provide me a way to get to print the rows // iterate over rows.

Comment: If the content of the query argument is a KQL query and not a command (e.g. .show,  .alter, etc.), you should use the query API.